# How to count number of certain object in an image without template matching?

Tags: image-processing

Design and describe a system to efficiently extract the relevant regions corresponding to the individual marbles in the image.
How to count the number of marbles in the scene (i) allowed
to prescribe a template; (ii) not allowed to prescribe any template as input.

(i) I think we can use SSD to compare the similarity of the input and template to count number of marbles.

(ii)I am not sure how to answer it,K-means or thresholding or watershed algorithm are used for segmentation. What kind of method or algorithm do we have to count these marbles without using template?

[image]

Comment: Similar to iris detection: The derivatives at the marble's edges all point to the center locations. For each pixel, compute how many derivatives point towards it. Use e.g. thresholding to discard non-center points.

Comment: I'd use HoughCircles.

Comment: @Bill I think the hough gradient method works pretty similar to what I described above, good to know its correct name.

Comment: @le_m I never really considered HoughCircles to work as a gradient direction method. But I guess it is. Sounds like we both learned something.